# how auto submit a session based form?

Tags: php, session, curl, form-submit

i have a form and want to submit it with a script.
i'm going to use curl function in php to do it.
but the form is not submit directly.

it have 3 steps and at the end of each step it store entered value in session variables and at the final steps it  insert record to database with the values are read from sessions.

it is possible to do auto submit this form using curl or not?
what is the best solution for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the --cookie-jar argument to curl to store the cookies that are returned with each request.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to perform it as a job. Store this information in your database instead of just the session and query for *pending submissions* with every request made to your site.